# Modal ViewController presenting another viewController won't animate immediately

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uiviewanimation, modal-view

Yes, I struggled a bit with that title...

Here's what my setup is meant to do:
I push a `viewController` (`resultViewController`) onto the navigation stack. Immediately (literally in the next line of code) I present another `viewController` to the `rootViewController` (`filterViewController`).

So far, so good, and things work as expected.

The modally presented `viewController` contains a `tableView`. Selecting a cell is supposed to present another `viewController` in the current (filterView) controller.

```
[self presentViewController:filterDetailsController animated:YES completion:^(void){
                         }];
```

This is where things go awry: The above snippets is called at the correct time, but the `viewController` does not appear until I perform an additional tap or gesture somewhere in the filterView. This suggest that the stacking of modalView inside modalView somehow messes things up. If I change the animated parameter to NO, the `viewController` is presented immediately.

An obvious work-around would be to set animated to NO and perform a manual animation in the completion block. I would however love to see if anyone have come across anything similar and knows how to fix the problem.

Comment: Have you tried presenting second controller in completion block ? may be timing issue in presenting with animation  [self presentViewController:filterDetailsController animated:YES completion:^(void){
                      //present second controller code  }];

Comment: Thanks, not sure if I understand you correctly (or the other way 'round): the above block is the block presenting the second viewController FROM the modal viewController ALREADY presented on the rootVC. It is only called when the user selects a cell in the first modalVC's tableView.